# How to Convert java.io.ObjectInputStream to java.util.stream.Stream?

Tags: java, java-8, inputstream, java-io, java-stream

Is there a straight forward way of using `java.io.ObjectInputStream` with `java.util.stream.Stream`?

It seems that `java.io.BufferedReader.lines` is provided to convert a buffered reader into a Stream but there doesn't seem to be an equivalent for Object's.

Has anyone have good solution for this conversion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ObjectInputStream can read a lot more than Objects.  The class implements DataInput, so it can read all kinds of data.  Then there's special methods like `readUnshared`.  So a Stream would be a pretty limited subset of ObjectInputStream's functonality.

But if you just want to read Objects one by one, you can write your own method:

```
public Stream<Object> toStream(final ObjectInputStream stream) {
    return Stream.generate(() -> readObject(stream)).onClose(
        () -> close(stream));
}

private static Object readObject(ObjectInputStream stream) {
    try {
        return stream.readObject();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

private static void close(Closeable c) {
    try {
        c.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Couldn't close " + c, e);
    }
}
```

You could even have a typed stream:

```
public <T> Stream<T> toStream(final ObjectInputStream stream,
                              final Class<T> cls) {
    return Stream.generate(() -> cls.cast(readObject(stream))).onClose(
        () -> close(stream));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think that's pretty much what I'll do. I was looking at how to pass `Object`'s captured from a socket through a chain of functions to modify and sort them. Passing them directly into a `Stream` seemed like it could be a nice way rather than putting them into something like a `LinkedBlockingDeque<Object>`

Comment: You can convert *any* stream to a differently typed stream by simply calling `map(cls::cast)` on it if you are confident that the type cast will always succeed. The tricky thing about the stream is that it will always terminate with an exception if you don’t `limit` it as `Stream.generate` creates an infinite stream which will always try to read another object from the input stream while the `ObjectInputStream` is finite in most cases (but doesn’t tell you how many objects you can read)…

Comment: Also, it occurs to me that if you forget about the original ObjectInputStream and only keep a reference to the Stream, you have no way to close the original ObjectInputStream.  I've updated my code so closing the Stream closes the original ObjectInputStream, but even that will require the Stream to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

this solution produces a finite stream without throwing `EOFException` at the end. It also closes the stream gracefully at the end. I had to implement a Spliterator that tries a read on `hasNext()` and returns the element read on `next()`.

```
public static <T> Stream<T> toStream(final ObjectInputStream stream,
                              final Class<T> cls) {

    Spliterator<T> spliterator = Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(new Iterator<T>() {

        private T next;
        private boolean read = false;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            if (!read) {
                try {
                    next = cls.cast(stream.readUnshared());
                } catch (EOFException e) {
                    next = null;
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
                }
                read = true;
            }
            return next != null;
        }

        @Override
        public T next() {
            read = false;
            return next;
        }
    }, Spliterator.DISTINCT | Spliterator.IMMUTABLE |
            Spliterator.ORDERED | Spliterator.NONNULL);

    return StreamSupport.stream(spliterator, false).onClose(() -> {
        try {
            stream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
```